# TemplateDoesNotExist at /travello

Tags: python, django

I have got an error. How can solve this problem.
When I was browsing:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/travello

Got an Error:
TemplateDoesNotExist at /travello
index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/travello
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:
index.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\musat\Envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Python Executable:  C:\Users\musat\Envs\myenv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:
['C:\Users\musat\projects\telusko',
'C:\Program Files\Hexagon\ERDAS IMAGINE '
'2015\usr\lib\Win32Release\python',
'C:\Users\musat\Envs\myenv\Scripts\python38.zip',
'c:\users\musat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\DLLs',
'c:\users\musat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib',
'c:\users\musat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38',
'C:\Users\musat\Envs\myenv',
'C:\Users\musat\Envs\myenv\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 08 Sep 2020 04:57:26 +0000

Comment: it says `index.html` file doesn't exists. you need to create an `index.html` file in the templates directory in your app(`telusko`) folder

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show any code, how are you expecting anyone to help??
Anyway you did an error while rendering it, here is how to do it:

```
return render(request, 'appname/index.html')
```

Now in the same app, you will create a new folder called templates     must be the same name, key sensitive
inside it put another folder holding your app name    e.g. app name
Inside the second one place your HTML files

It should look like this at the end

```
appname
----views.py
----models.py
----templates
--------appname
------------index.html
------------otherpages.html
```